# Setting DataContext within UserControl is affecting bindings in parent

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls, datacontext

I have a basic `UserControl` that sets its `DataContext` to itself for ease of binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControlLib.ChildControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 

             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

</UserControl>
```

This is used in a parent XAML file like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControlLib.ParentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:MyControlLib">

             <ctrl:ChildControl x:Name="ChildName" 
                                PropertyOnChild="{Binding PropertyInParentContext}"/>             
</UserControl>
```

For some reason, this gives a binding error that seems to indicate that the `DataContext` of the parent control is getting affected by the child control setting its own `DataContext`.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PropertyInParentContext' property not found on 'object' ''ChildControl' (Name='ChildName')'. BindingExpression:Path=PropertyInParentContext; DataItem='ChildControl' (Name='ChildName'); target element is 'ChildControl' (Name='ChildName'); target property is 'PropertyOnChild' (type 'whatever')

Why is "PropertyInParentContext" being looking for in the child control rather than in the parent's `DataContext`?

If I remove the

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

from the child control, then things operate how I would expect.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The declaration of your control and the instantiation are basically manipulating the same object, all the properties that are set in the declaration are also set on every instance. So if the properties were "visible" so to speak:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControlLib.ParentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:MyControlLib">
    <ctrl:ChildControl x:Name="ChildName" 
                       DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                       PropertyOnChild="{Binding PropertyInParentContext}"/>
</UserControl>
```

This is why you do not set the `DataContext` of `UserControls`, it will override the inherited `DataContext` (and even obfuscate the fact that there is a different context). If you want to bind to properties of the `UserControl` in its declaration then name the control and use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`-bindings instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was misunderstanding the scope of the bindings and your post explained it pretty well. I was thinking that the XAML of a UserControl is self contained, like in a template, but I guess it's all just part of the document.

Answer (score 5):

`Self` means the `UserControl`, so when you set the `DataContext` to `Self`, you are setting the `DataContext` to the `UserControl` object.

The correct syntax for binding to a Control's `DataContext` would be `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}`, however since the DataContext is inherited by the Parent, this binding is totally unncessary in any situation.

Also, if you bind your `DataContext` to `Self.DataContext`, you would essentially be creating a loop where a value is bound to itself.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to do - set the DataContext to the UserControl. I didn't understand that this would effect the binding statements in the "parent" control.