# DataTrigger does not fire on a derived class of a Button

Tags: wpf, button, dependency-properties, multidatatrigger

We have a ton of Buttons with an Icon and Text across the App, and I am trying to extract a common style for all of them. I came up with this idea of deriving from a Button and have a couple of dependency properties. This custom button class has a style common to all the Buttons in our Application.

**My Custom Button definition:**

```
<Button x:Class="UIElements.Controls.CustomToolBarButton"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
               xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
               xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" mc:Ignorable="d"
               >
<!--Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ToolBarButtonStyle}"-->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{Binding Icon, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ToolBarButtonIconStyle}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ToolBarButtonDisplayTextStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
//using Telerik.Windows.Controls;

namespace UIElements.Controls
{
    public partial class CustomToolBarButton : Button
    {
        public CustomToolBarButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(BitmapImage), typeof(Button), new PropertyMetadata(default(BitmapImage)));

        public BitmapImage Icon
        {
            get { return (BitmapImage)GetValue(IconProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayText", typeof(string), typeof(Button), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string DisplayText
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(DisplayTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayTextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

**And I am using this control as follows:**

```
<Controls1:CustomToolBarButton Icon="{DynamicResource ImageSave}"
                        DisplayText="Test Display">
<Controls1:CustomToolBarButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Controls1:CustomToolBarButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedListItem.ListId}" Value="0" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <!--<Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />-->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Controls1:CustomToolBarButton.Style>
```

Things look good, however the trigger is not firing when the bounded data changes. If I apply the same trigger to the regular button, it seems to be working fine.

Could you please tell me if I am missing something?

**EDIT:**
Found an [elegant solution](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/01/create-wpf-image-button-through-attached-properties). Made use of Attached Properties

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your static constructor

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomToolBarButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomToolBarButton)));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey.aspx

Comment: More information? Are you getting anything in output, binding errors etc?

Answer (score 0):

In your `CustomToolBarButton`, you are setting it's `DataContext` to the button itself(`this.DataContext = this;`). By doing this you have stopped the propagation of the parent(parent control of your button, say grid or UserControl) data-context to your button(which contains the `SelectedListItem` property).

In case you just want to fix this, try to use `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` Binding to access the buttons parent control and then use it's `DataContext` to access the `SelectedListItem`.

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">

    <Controls1:CustomToolBarButton Icon="{DynamicResource ImageSave}"
                            DisplayText="Test Display">
    <Controls1:CustomToolBarButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Controls1:CustomToolBarButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=ParentGrid,
                           Path=DataContext.SelectedListItem.ListId}" Value="0" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <!--<Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />-->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Controls1:CustomToolBarButton.Style>
</Grid>
```

The problem is happening as you have used a UserControl to extend the Button; as you said you have a ton of buttons, I would suggest you to create a `CustomControl` with template, like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17830/Creating-and-consuming-a-custom-WPF-control); that way you won't have to mess with the DataContext propagation.

Here is a blog explaining different ways of doing exactly what you want -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx

Comment: Thank you Akjoshi, In the link to the blog, there was a comment that mentioned the use of an attached property to achieve the same..

Comment: Yes, using content template is also a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should [never use `this.DataContext = this;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572005/setting-datacontext-within-usercontrol-is-affecting-bindings-in-parent/7573570#7573570), ever.

Secondly if you inherit from button you should not create a XAML file but a default style in the `Themes/Generic.xaml` resource dictionary (if you inherit from `UserControl` a file like this is fine).

This will also mean that you will need to define a [`Control.Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) in the style and hence should use [`TemplateBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatebindingextension.aspx) instead of normal ones (or use [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx)).

As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465617/546730) you may need to override the metadata.