# How do I reference a custom property value in a WPF UserControl via Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I'm building a WPF app with custom UserControls, and I'm trying to understand how property bindings are supposed to work. I can't get even the most basic binding to work, and it's simple enough to distill into a tiny example, so I figured someone with more WPF experience might be able to put me on the right track.

I've defined a custom UserControl called **TestControl**, which exposes a **Foo** property, which is intended to be set in XAML whenever a UserControl is placed.

**TestControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BindingTest
{
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Foo", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl));
        public string Foo
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(FooProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FooProperty, value); }
        }

        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The markup for TestControl just defines it as a control with a single button, whose label text displays the current value of the Foo property:

**TestControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Foo}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my **MainWindow** class, I just place a single instance of TestControl with its Foo property set to "Hello".

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl Foo="Hello" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would expect that when I build and launch this app, I'd see a window with a single button reading "Hello". However, the button is blank: the Binding doesn't seem to work.

If I add a click handler to the TestControl's button, I can verify that the value is being updated behind the scenes:

```cs
// Added to TestControl.xaml.cs:
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Button clicked; Foo is '{0}'", Foo);
}

// Updated in TestControl.xaml:
// <Button Content="{Binding Foo}" Click="Button_Click" />
```

When I click the button, I get `Button clicked; Foo is 'Hello'`, but the GUI never updates. I've tried using `Path=Foo`, `XPath=Foo`, etc., as well as setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and verifying updates with `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True`... nothing seems to result in the text in the UI being updated to match the underlying property value, even though the property value seems to be getting updated just fine.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like there's just a simple and fundamental misunderstanding in how I'm approaching this.

**edit:**

Poking around a bit more and reading [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993498/wpf-usercontrol-property-binding) has led me to a potential fix: namely, adding a name to the root UserControl element in TestControl.xaml (`x:Name="control"`), and changing the binding to explicitly specify that control (`{Binding Foo, ElementName=control}`).

I'm guessing that by default, `{Binding Foo}` on the Button element just means *"find a property named 'Foo' on this Button control"*, whereas I'd assumed it'd mean *"find a property named 'Foo' in the context that this Button is being declared in, i.e. on the TestControl"*.

Is specifying an explicit ElementName the best fix here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the source object of the Binding to the UserControl instance, e.g. like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

or

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="theControl">
...
<Button Content="{Binding Foo, ElementName=theControl}"/>
```

---

If you have many such Bindings, you may also set the DataContext of the top level element in the UserControl's XAML to the UserControl instance:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Button Content="{Binding Foo}" />
    <Button Content="{Binding Bar}" />
</Grid>
```

---

You must however avoid to set the DataContext of the UserControl (which is often recommend by "expert" bloggers), because that would break DataContext-based Bindings of the UserControl properties like

```
<local:TestControl Foo="{Binding SomeFoo}" />
```

Comment: Beautiful! Overriding the DataContext for the entire control is the approach I was hoping was possible. And, in general, the concept of Bindings having a "DataContext" is the piece of the puzzle I was missing. Thanks for the fix, the vocabulary, and the heads-up about the UserControl/DataContext pitfall.

Comment: *Overriding the DataContext for the entire control* is exactly what you should avoid! See the explanation above.

Comment: Ah, I can see how my wording would be misleading. I'm just referring to your second example, i.e. setting a DataContext on the top-level element beneath the root control (i.e. the Grid, in this example).