# WPF TextBlock binding not updating with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following custom `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl ... x:Class="Controls.CurrentUser">
  <Border Background="#253f95" Margin="5">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
      <Image Height="48" Width="48" Source="anonymous.png">
        <Image.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip Background="#253f95">
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Name}" />
              <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Organization}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </ToolTip>
        </Image.ToolTip>
      </Image>
      <Button Content="Disconnect" Margin="10,0,5,0" Click="DisconnectClicked" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I've tried several suggestions that I've read through SO and still can't get the simple binding text to display... Initially, the `UserControl` is being initialized in the MainWindow's XAML with no `User` object being set. I later on set the `User` object, but it won't update the value even using `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

This is the custom UserControl:

```
public partial class CurrentUser : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private User _user;

  private string _displayName;
  private string _orgName;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get { return _displayName; }
    set {
        _displayName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  public string Organization
  {
    get { return _orgName; }
    set
    {
        _orgName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Organization");
    }
  }

  public CurrentUser()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  ~CurrentUser()
  {
    _user = null;
  }

  public void SetUser(User user)
  {
    _user = user;
    _user.OnUserConnected += () =>
    {
      // yes, this was being triggered when I set a breakpoint
      // and the value weren't null nor empty
      Name = _user.Name;
      Organization = _user.Company;
    };
  }
}
```

It should work even without `INotifyPropertyChange`... but it seems I am missing something obvious?

PS: I've tried the solutions in this thread without success:
[WPF binding not updating the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522218/wpf-binding-not-updating-the-view)

Comment: Use `Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Comment: The UserControl properties should be [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/custom-dependency-properties?view=netdesktop-7.0). Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is pointless.

Comment: If you have binding errors, in order not to miss them have a look at this post: [Writing a `BindingErrorListener` class to catch binding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74929717/2638227).

Comment: Having your UI class (`CurrentUser` here) implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is odd to me. Normally UI classes will not implement this interface but have a  base view model class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` as their `DataContext`.

Comment: Whoever closed the question, obviously didn't read my question, I said I already read through the "duplicated" question. But anyway, with the help of the answers above and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533698/how-do-i-reference-a-custom-property-value-in-a-wpf-usercontrol-via-binding

I actually need to pass the `DataContext` at the wrapper `StackPanel`.

Comment: @Clemens I don't see it being the same, because I definitely tried binding your way and that did not work. I also found out that, setting it directly on the `UserControl` like this worked `<UserControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">`

Comment: Than you must have done something wrong. Both ElementName and RelativeSource Bindings will work as shown in the answers.

Comment: Setting the UserControl's DataContext like that is a programming error. It breaks the standard binding behavior when you try to bind a property of the control.

Comment: @Clemens As mentioned, none of the things I tried worked, and the only thing that worked was the "programming error" but with this thread closed, I will never find out what's the real error. Thanks.

Comment: The "real error" was obviously that you did not use an ElementName or a RelativeSource Binding, at least not in the code in your question.

Comment: @Clemens So is it an error or not? This accepted answer showed that is not a "programming error", https://stackoverflow.com/a/5077461/1009046, so which is it?

Comment: You will find many other sources like blog post that recomment explicitly setting a UserControl's DataContext to the control itself. It is still wrong. If you do that, standard bindings like `<CurrentUser Background="{Binding SomeBackground}"/>` that bind to properties of a view model in the DataContext of the parent Window or Page will no longer work. Try it yourself. And read the comments on that answer. Not every accepted answer on StackOverflow is a good answer.

Comment: You could alternatively set the DataContext of the top level element in the UserControl's XAML like `<Border ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">`

Comment: And don't forget to turn the control's properties into dependency properties. UIElements (or any other DependencyObjects) do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.